# magento - import configurable product with magmi

Tags: magento, magmi

Before posting this question, I've tried ways to make this work but it doesn't.

This is the csv structure:

```
|model - map to sku
|name
|price
|category - map to categories
|loc
|image - use image plugin - works fine
|description
|weight
|option_type
|option_value
|suggested_retail
|special_handling
|manufacturer
|manufacturer_code
|packaging
|in_stock
|last_updated
|active
|visibility : default mapper plugin, value: 'Catalog, Search'
|configurable_attributes : default mapper plugin, value: 'manufacturer,color'
```

example csv file: http://pastebin.com/kRW2vQrY.

All simple products are imported fine but the configurable ones don't. I already activate the configurable items with these settings:

```
Perform simples/configurable link Yes
auto match simples skus before configurable Yes
Force simples visibility No
```

**I want to know why it doesn't work and solution for this problem ?** 
Thanks for reading :)

Comment: You also need to specify simples_skus for each configurable product; i'm not quite sure if it will help, but i see no mistakes except this one

Comment: I've get configurable product created by adding another csv column 'type' and create new configurable one. 
But the simple product doesn't seem to link to the configurable one.

Comment: There are two ways for linking configurable products and simple: By default magmi links one configurable with the previous simple products found. That could be overriden by setting a new CSV field "simples_skus" with a comma separated list of simples to be attached to the configurable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I solve the problem by writing my own parser to map some specifics column from original csv to magmi's csv structure. And I also create another file for configurable product with new two columns :

```
  type : 'configurable'
  simples_skus: list of simple skus
```

Thanks for reading and discussing :)

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the automatic mapping, it is based on the attributes you specify for configurable_attributes (in your case manufacturer,colour). However, your csv structure does not seem to include values for the colour attribute